# Where is the room with the stargate?

Tags: fez

I remember walking into a room and dot saying something along the lines of "I can't believe it! A working stargate", but I didnt go through it because I didn't know if it was the end. I'm assuming that was the end of the game.

Problem is, I don't know where that room is anymore. The only anticubes I have left are the first person puzzles, which you get after you beat the game.

Where is it? How can I find it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's in the "modern temple" area (the 16-cube door), behind the large 32-cube door.**

[image: 32-cube door]

It'll show as a large black opening if you've already been inside.

Answer (score 1):

Go back to the first warp gate, then through the purple door where you came in for the first time to the area with the 4, 8 and 16 cube doors. The under-construction 'big-head' village (or the 'modern temple') is though the 16 cube door.

The 4 door leads to your 2D ancestors village (according to the evolution chart in the class room). The 8 door to the neon city.

Dot says *"I can't believe it! A working stargate"* in the under-construction big-head village because there's also a space-infected one in the ruined big-head village.

Also in that village are 4 murals in another room showing:

- The gate being started
- The gate being built
- The finished gate with 4 big-heads wear a fez each.
- The gate destroyed by space holes (as you see it in the ruined village)